# Setting condition in Salary Head in OpenERP

Tags: python, odoo

I'm implementing HR module in OpenERP I am trying to setup a condition in Salary Head like:

```
if Basic > 0 and basic <=5000:
   ProfessionalTax = 80
else if 
   Basic > 5000 and basic <= 10000
   ProfessionalTax = 150
```

Can anybody help me with the syntax? I have not had any luck finding this information.

Answer (score 2):

[The Python if statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#if) uses `elif` to mean `else if`. Your example would be as follows:

```
if basic > 0 and basic <=5000:
   ProfessionalTax = 80
elif basic > 5000 and basic <= 10000:
   ProfessionalTax = 150
```

I also had to move the condition up onto the same line as `elif`. Remember that line breaks and white space have meaning in Python. Variable names are case-sensitive, so I guessed that you only had one variable named `basic` and made them all the same.